# Uploadify not uploading all files in multi upload

Tags: uploadify

I'm trying to implement the multi upload with uploadify. It works find for the first couple files I've selected, but the rest of the files I've selected don't upload.  I've checked the settings for post_max_size (set to 20M), max_file_uploads (set to 20) and max_execution_time (set to 120) - which should be sufficient for what I'm uploading.  Any ideas as to why only the first couple files would be uploading?

Comment: You need to show your code so we can see how you are using Uploadify. Also what version, which browser etc.

Comment: ... and if you do not return the site to answer queries, you are unlikely to get answers :)